# Python why 100**0.5 == 4+6 is true？

Tags: python

```
>>> 100**0.5 != 4+6
False
>>> 100**0.5 == 4+6
True
>>> 4+6
10
>>> 100**0.5
10.0
>>> 10.0==10
True
```

Who can tell me why `10.0==10` is `True`?
I think 10.0 is a `float` and 10 is `int`，I know in java they are not equal.

Comment: "I know in java they are not equal" - but they are.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

> Python fully supports mixed arithmetic: when a binary arithmetic
>   operator has operands of different numeric types, the operand with the
>   “narrower” type is widened to that of the other, where plain integer
>   is narrower than long integer is narrower than floating point is
>   narrower than complex.

So, `10` is widened to `10.0`. Thats why `10 == 10.0`

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the way Python defines equality for floats and integers. If the float represents a whole number, it's equal to the integer representing the same number (and even has the same hash code). Note that Java does something to similar effect (even though `==` cannot be overloaded by classes in Java). `10.0 == 10` is true because `==` with mixed (numeric) arguments performs [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1) which turns the int `10` into the floating point number `10.0`.

Answer (score 1):

u can use

```
>>> 10 == 10.0
True
>>> 10 is 10.0
False
```

**is** is the identity comparison.

**==** is the equality comparison.

`is` means *is same instance*. It evaluates to true if the variables on either side of the operator point to the same object and false otherwise.

Comment: This should not have 3 upvotes, considering that it is completely wrong. `1000 is 400 + 600` gives `False`, because `is` tests object identity, and different objects may represent the same number.

Comment: i have edited my answer for better understanding..!!

Comment: `is` is still completely inappropriate for this situation. Identity comparison is not desirable here.

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically type converts during comparisons if possible and sensible to do so.

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True == 0
False
>>> True == 22
False
```

Also illustrates this behaviour.